# glibc-2.24 fails to compile on LFS system, log says -V argument is not recognised, but i'm not passing -V

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I am stuck on step 5.7 of Linux From Scratch 7.10. I'm trying to compile glibc, but its returning the following error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.24/build':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

Contents of config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Library configure (see version.h), which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ../configure --prefix=/tools --host= --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --enable-kernel=2.6.32 --with-headers=/tools/include libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = gradyn-external
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.8.0-32-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #34-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 13 14:30:43 UTC 2016

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: .


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2189: checking build system type
configure:2203: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2223: checking host system type
configure:2236: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2305: checking for gcc
configure:2321: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2332: result: gcc
configure:2561: checking for C compiler version
configure:2570: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2581: $? = 0
configure:2570: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 
configure:2581: $? = 0
configure:2570: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2581: $? = 1
configure:2570: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2581: $? = 1
configure:2586: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2608: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
configure:2612: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
| #define PKGVERSION "(GNU libc) "
| #define REPORT_BUGS_TO "<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2626: error: in `/mnt/lfs/sources/glibc-2.24/build':
configure:2628: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes
libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS_config=''
AUTOCONF=''
AWK=''
BASH_SHELL=''
BISON=''
BUILD_CC=''
CC='gcc'
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPUNDEFS=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CXX_SYSINCLUDES=''
DEFINES=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_INFO=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LD=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBGD=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKE=''
MAKEINFO=''
MSGFMT=''
NM=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/'
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU C Library'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU C Library (see version.h)'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='glibc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='(see version.h)'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PKGVERSION='(GNU libc) '
PKGVERSION_TEXI='(GNU libc) '
READELF=''
RELEASE=''
REPORT_BUGS_TEXI='@uref{http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html}'
REPORT_BUGS_TO='<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>'
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SYSINCLUDES=''
VERSION=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
add_on_subdirs=''
add_ons=''
all_warnings=''
base_machine=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
bindnow=''
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_nscd=''
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_pt_chown=''
build_vendor='pc'
cross_compiling='no'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_lock_elision=''
enable_timezone_tools=''
enable_werror=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
fno_unit_at_a_time=''
force_install=''
hardcoded_path_in_tests=''
have_libaudit=''
have_libcap=''
have_selinux=''
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
ldd_rewrite_script=''
libc_cv_cc_loop_to_function=''
libc_cv_cc_nofma=''
libc_cv_cc_submachine=''
libc_cv_cc_with_libunwind=''
libc_cv_complocaledir=''
libc_cv_cxx_thread_local=''
libc_cv_fpie=''
libc_cv_gcc_unwind_find_fde=''
libc_cv_has_glob_dat=''
libc_cv_hashstyle=''
libc_cv_localstatedir=''
libc_cv_mtls_dialect_gnu2=''
libc_cv_nss_crypt=''
libc_cv_output_format=''
libc_cv_pic_default=''
libc_cv_pie_default=''
libc_cv_protected_data=''
libc_cv_rootsbindir=''
libc_cv_rtlddir=''
libc_cv_slibdir=''
libc_cv_sysconfdir=''
libc_cv_z_combreloc=''
libc_cv_z_execstack=''
libc_extra_cflags=''
libc_extra_cppflags=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
link_obsolete_rpc=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mach_interface_list=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
multi_arch=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/tools'
profile=''
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
shared=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
stack_protector=''
static=''
static_nss=''
subdirs=' '
submachine=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
sysdeps_add_ons=''
sysheaders=''
sysnames=''
target_alias=''
use_default_link=''
use_ldconfig=''
use_nscd=''
with_fp=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
#define PKGVERSION "(GNU libc) "
#define REPORT_BUGS_TO "<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>"

configure: exit 1
```

I have allredy compiled binutils, gcc, and the the linux kernel

Here is the command i am running:

```
../configure                             \
      --prefix=/tools                    \
      --host=$LFS_TGT                    \
      --build=$(../scripts/config.guess) \
      --enable-kernel=2.6.32             \
      --with-headers=/tools/include      \
      libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes          \
      libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is *not* `gcc -V`.

Your problem is this:

```
configure:2608: gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

This means that the `gcc` you are using is not installed correctly, and can't actually compile anything.